# Swift - How to change the color of an accessoryType (disclosureIndicator)?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell

I have question about the `accessoryType` of cells. I am using a cell with an `disclosureIndicator` as `accessoryType` and I want to change it's color but I can't.
Does anyone know if this is a bug or if Apple forces me to use the grey color? 
Actually I can change the colors of other `accessoryType`.

My code looks like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) as! customCell
cell.tintColor = UIColor.red
cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
```

And my arrow is still grey. But if I use a checkmark `accessoryType` it becomes red.

Is there any way to fix this or do I have to use a colored image?

Comment: Based on numerous posts and articles (although I can't find anything in Apple's docs), it appears `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` **cannot** be tinted. Best bet is to use an image with rendering mode set to `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`. See this post for details and example code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955447/uitableviewcell-accessory-not-being-tinted

Comment: You can't change the `disclosureIndicator`'s color.

Comment: @k8mil I think this question is not duplicate or duplicated. It's about a `disclosureIndicator` not the `checkmark`.

Comment: You could just use a custom UITableViewCell and set up the image view with a chevron however you like.

Comment: @k8mil @Mannopson is right. This is not a duplicate question because the answer doesn't work for `disclosureIndicator`

Comment: In swift 5.x, **cell.tintColor** doesn't change **disclosureIndicator's** color. better use image.  cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "chevronright"))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.tintColor = UIColor.white

    let image = UIImage(named: "Arrow.png")
    let checkmark  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:(image?.size.width)!, height:(image?.size.height)!));
    checkmark.image = image
    cell.accessoryView = checkmark

    let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate
    cell.textLabel!.text = object.description
    return cell
}
```

**Sample Arrow Images**

[image] [image]

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Use SF Symbol

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right")
let accessory  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:(image?.size.width)!, height:(image?.size.height)!))
accessory.image = image

// set the color here
accessory.tintColor = UIColor.white
cell.accessoryView = accessory
```

Answer (score 6):

**Updated for Swift 4.2 with images attached**:

```
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    cell.tintColor = .black
    let image = UIImage(named:"disclosureArrow")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    if let width = image?.size.width, let height = image?.size.height {
        let disclosureImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        disclosureImageView.image = image
        cell.accessoryView = disclosureImageView
    }
```

**Images you can use:**

[image: 1x][image: 2x][image: 3x]

***What it could look like:***

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

Bellow Code is **Swift 3.0** code, and will change the **accessoryType color as per tintColor.**

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "SOME TITLE GOES HERE"

    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

    cell.tintColor = UIColor.blue


    let image = UIImage(named:"arrow1")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

    let checkmark  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:(image?.size.width)!, height:(image?.size.height)!));
    checkmark.image = image
    cell.accessoryView = checkmark

    return cell
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5 & iOS 15 & Xcode 13**

Here is an extension which uses SF Symbols, so you have a chevron like the default disclosure indicator one:

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    func addCustomDisclosureIndicator(with color: UIColor) {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 15))
        let symbolConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 15, weight: .regular, scale: .large)
        let symbolImage = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right",
                                  withConfiguration: symbolConfig)
        button.setImage(symbolImage?.withTintColor(color, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = color
        self.accessoryView = button
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.addCustomDisclosureIndicator(with: .white) // Here your own color
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I found this worked, but the following line needs updated as it's hard coding the chevron colour to white instead of the passed in colour.

`button.setImage(symbolImage?.withTintColor(color, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)`

Comment: @MalcolmMurray thank you, just fixed it! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**. **Extension** style ;)

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    func setupDisclosureIndicator() {
        accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 7, height: 12))
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imgView.image = UIImage(named: "your_icon_name")
        accessoryView = imgView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 & iOS 11-15**

A combination of some answers

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    func addCustomDisclosureIndicator(with color: UIColor) {
        accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        let disclosureImage = UIImage(named: "arrow_right")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let imageWidth = (disclosureImage?.size.width) ?? 7
        let imageHeight = (disclosureImage?.size.height) ?? 12
        let accessoryImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight))
        accessoryImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        accessoryImageView.image = disclosureImage
        accessoryImageView.tintColor = color
        accessoryView = accessoryImageView
    }
}
```